# How to query only limited columns in Hibernate, and map them to a given POJO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, graphql

My project involves using GraphQL within a Spring Boot app. For demonstration purposes, here is my GraphQL schema:

```
type Company{
  name: String,
  parentOrganization: String,
  flag:Int
}
```

I'm still learning Spring Boot and JPA, so I use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` for all the JPA, Hibernate, etc.

My problem is, when someone queries only for `name` and `organization`, Hibernate queries for **all** the columns and GraphQL picks the columns requested.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company,Long> {

}
```

The above code doesn't really give me any flexibility in limiting the columns that are queried. I've tried using Hibernate's Criteria API as well, but whichever way I go, I get this error:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [packagee.entity.company]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String [select new package.entity.Company(generatedAlias0.company, generatedAlias0.organization) from package.entity.Company as generatedAlias0]
```

Below is the code for my Criteria implementation:

```
    public static List<Company> get(EntityManager em, List<String> fieldsAsked){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Company> cq = cb.createQuery(Company.class);

        Root<Company> root = cq.from(Company.class);
        List<Selection<?>> selectionList = new LinkedList<Selection<?>>();

        for(String name: fieldsAsked){
            selectionList.add(root.get(name));
        }
        cq.multiselect(selectionList);

        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
```

How do I get limited columns from Hibernate? I've seen many answers online that ask to make appropriate constructor in the entity class, but that's not really possible for me because my entity parameters are mostly Strings and I cant make constructors for all the permutations possible (because I'm using GraphQL, the control of what to query really goes to the end user of my project).

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using GraphQLQueryResolver ? Can this solve your issue https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Comment: I'm using GraphQLQueryResolver only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not really possible with Hibernate directly, but you can checkout [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which also has a GraphQL integration that supports exactly what you are looking for. See https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#graphql-integration

Here is a sample project that shows how you can use this: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/master/examples/spring-data-graphql

Comment: I've decided that I'm sort-of okay with my project fetching all records, it wouldnt be as big of a performance difference anyway. But since you've come up with an alternative I can sort-of go with, I'll accept this one. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't make a big difference, that's true, but in general, this is just unnecessary work the database has to do and unnecessary network traffic. This will be a problem if the columns are wide or you have many of them, but also if you join *-to-many associations as that will change the cardinality to N * M. Mix that with multiple *-to-many associations and you fetch 1k+ rows where the amount of columns starts to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

You can create a new DTO class which will be returned by your query.

The DTO class:

```
public class CompanyDTO(){
   //fields,constructor
}
```

And in the repository:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.dto.companyDTO" +
        "(c.name,c.parentOrganization)" +
        " FROM Company c")
    List<CompanyDTO>findCompanySelectedColumns(PageRequest pageable);
```

Solution 2(clean solution):

You can use interface. **Do not implement the interface**.

```
interface customCustomer{
   String getName();
   String getParentOrganization();
}
```

In repository:

```
List<CustomCustomer>findAllByNameAndParentOrganization();
```

Comment: Problem with this is that because the control of what to query is with the user using GraphQL, I cannot really make DTO classes or constructors for every single combination of fields passed.
Aside from CompanyDTO, I have 5 other DTO's, with 7 fields in them each. Isnt there a way to do this without making constructors or DTOs?

Comment: I'm sorry if my previous comment wasnt clear, but is there no other way of querying data with Hibernate without making all the constructors and the interfaces? Because I cant see the difference in implementing an interface and making the constructors: both are unfeasible for me.

Comment: You can always use native query.@Query(value = "SELECT name, parentOrganization FROM Company";, nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findCompanyNameAndParentOrganization();